# 2008 scion tc electrical issue

Tags: electrical, obd-ii, ignition, electronic-control-module, battery-drain

Hey there I have a 2008 scion tc manual transmission. I’ve ran into the problem of the car reading 12v at idle, 11.5 when lights and heat are on and 10.9 when driving. I checked that the alternator is charging and it is at 14v I checked at the battery and also at 14v but when I check the scanner it reads 11.2. While the car is running and at the same time checking the battery that reads 14v. Is this an ecu issue or ignition. The car also tries to shut off if the speed drops and or if the defrosters get turned on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you examine main ground connections for severe corrosion, loose connections? Examine battery positive branching out to engine fuse box and starter?